# vyos - error message "respawning too fast"

Tags: vyos

Just pulled down the ISO for the latest stable vyos today, 1.1.8, and ran on my Mac under VirtualBox. It emits this message about every 5 minutes:

```
INIT: Id "TO" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes
```

What is that about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter the router configuration mode and execute the following commands:

```
# delete system console device ttyS0
# commit
# save
# exit
```

After that just reboot the system. This error is because if you were to install VyOS in a hardware appliance a serial port is required before you can connect via SSH but since you're running it on a VM you don't need the ttys0. Hope it helps!